# Java import AWS Access Keys from Session

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, sdk

I am writing a script in Java that calls an API Gateway endpoint. However in order for my script to work I need to it pass the AWS access keys and session token. Currently my code works but the AWS keys are hard-coded. How can I pass the keys without hardcoding them? Here is my current code:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import auth.AWS4SignerBase;
import auth.AWS4SignerForAuthorizationHeader;
import util.HttpUtils;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    URL endpointUrl = new URL("https://lmno456.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/controlplane/model/a1");

    var regionName = "us-east-1";
    var awsAccessKey = "abc123";
    var awsSecretKey = "def234";
    var awsSessionToken = "xyz789==";

    // for a simple GET, we have no body so supply the precomputed 'empty' hash
    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
    headers.put("x-amz-content-sha256", AWS4SignerBase.EMPTY_BODY_SHA256);
    headers.put("X-Amz-Security-Token", awsSessionToken);

    AWS4SignerForAuthorizationHeader signer = new AWS4SignerForAuthorizationHeader(endpointUrl, "GET", "execute-api", regionName);

    String authorization = signer.computeSignature(headers,
                                            null, // no query parameters
                                            AWS4SignerBase.EMPTY_BODY_SHA256,
                                            awsAccessKey,
                                            awsSecretKey);

    headers.put("Authorization", authorization);
    String response = HttpUtils.invokeHttpRequest(endpointUrl, "GET", headers, null);
    System.out.println("--------- Response content ---------");
    System.out.println(response);
    System.out.println("------------------------------------");
  }
}
```

Ideally I'm looking for something similar to python's boto3 `credentials = session.get_credentials()` to retrieve the access and session keys. I am doing this for an AWS lambda function.

Comment: if you use the aws sdk within lambda you have automatic credentials once you assign an [execution role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-intro-execution-role.html) to that lambda. And there's probably an invoke execute api thing that doesn't require you to manually sign requests. Running on EC2 instances you have similarly automatically the credentials of the Instance Role. And there are more ways to get credentials like from environment variables: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkref/latest/guide/standardized-credentials.html

Comment: You don't hardcode credentials, you would want to rely on the default credential chain: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/credentials.html

Comment: WHen you use Java SDK in an AWS Lambda function, you do not needs creds, You run the Lambda function as a IAM user that has permission to invoke the given service.

Comment: But what if I need to pass the access keys to another function in the code. Is there anyway to retrieve them from the lambda using java?

Comment: Nevermind, looks like I can get them from the lambda using `System.getenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID")`, `System.getenv("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY")`, `System.getenv("AWS_SESSION_TOKEN")`